# How do create a dropdown with categorical data?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

Sorry for such a vague question, but I really don't know what we call them, all I have is image like

[image]

How Do I create a dropdown where I can have parent category which can not be selected, but sub category can be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<optgroup>` element inside the select

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="test">
    <option value="value">value 1</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```